# Placing two drop-downs next to each other

Tags: html, css

How to place two select boxes next to each other inside the table-data of a table and it should also be responsive.

Please Help!! Thanks all

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you're talking about?

CSS:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

HTML:

```
table{
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

select{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/er2uekkL/1/)

Comment: Nope! I wanna include both the select boxes in a single td!

Comment: One more doubt? If I try to give the size of select element more than 50% it automatically gets placed one below the other.. what is the solution for this? Thanks

Comment: right because combined they can't go over 100% of the width. So you can tack on a class for one of them that overrides the original set height: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/er2uekkL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use table cols and rows attribute to span your table and rows 

<tr>
    <td><input type="text" ></td>
    <td rowspan=5><textarea rows="10" cols="35"> </textarea></td>       
    <td rowspan=5><textarea rows="10" cols="35"> </textarea></td>   
  </tr>
```

Something like this I think you can use